# Query M2M relations in Django

Tags: django, django-models, drf-queryset

I've the following model:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    month = models.DateField()

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, status=(('Pending', 'Pending'), ('Approved', 'Approved'))

class Contest(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, related_name='contest_questions')
```

Now I want to get list of quizes with all questions whose status=Pending?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is query directly from the M2M table using [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
quiz_ids = list(Contest.objects.filter(questions__status='Pending').values_list('quiz__id', flat=True))

quiz_query = Quiz.objects.filter(id__in=quiz_ids)
```